# Emacs hangs when run through SSHing to my Ubuntu Box (13.10)

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, ssh, ubuntu-13.10

Running Ubuntu 13.10, I cannot run emacs when sshing to my box

```
ssh -l username someipaddress
```

When I run emacs, it simply hangs.

I have also have recently installed dbus-x11 . Before installing dbus-x11, I would get a crash when trying to run emacs.

```
(emacs:3306): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

(emacs:3306): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

(emacs:3306): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

(emacs:3306): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

(emacs:3306): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

(emacs:3306): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
```

I have another ubuntu box (12.10) (vm though) running from a different provider.  However I have no issues running emacs.  In both cases I used apt-get to install emacs.

Comment: It sounds like it's trying to run Emacs in X; and you're not forwarding an X display. Try `emacs -nw`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Could you put your comment in an answer, you deserve credit.

Comment: Do you know how I can forward an X Display

Comment: The X11 forwarding is set up correctly

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like it's trying to run Emacs in X; and you're not forwarding an X display. Try `emacs -nw` to run it in a terminal. Alternately, if the machine you're SSHing *from* is running X, you can add `-X` or `-Y` on the SSH command line to forward X -- this makes it so that any X programs you run on the remote will show their windows on your local display.

(`-X` and `-Y` differ in that `-Y` tells SSH to treat the remote X clients as trusted; see [What is the difference between `ssh -Y` (trusted X11 forwarding) and `ssh -X` (untrusted X11 forwarding)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35512/what-is-the-difference-between-ssh-y-trusted-x11-forwarding-and-ssh-x-u) for more. I've found that if you use `-X` and have long-running X forwarding SSH connections, SSH will eventually close the forward; my understanding is that with `-Y` this won't happen until the SSH connection is closed.)

Answer (score 3):

Also check ownership of files/directories in your home dir (including hidden!)  Like the following response from archlinux.org suggested, my `~/.dbus` was root owned.

```
$ sudo chown -R myusrid:mygroupid ~/.dbus
```

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1233613#p1233613

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem and this solved it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install dbus-x11
```